# Small wireless proximity device to alert me when my cat gets into my WiFi range

Tags: wireless-communication, signal

I have the following situation. My cat goes outside every day, the problem is I have no way of telling when he is back around the house unless I go outside myself. 
I need some small wireless device I can attach to his collar that would alert me when he is in the range of my WiFi. GPS locators are just too big for a cat and movement detectors are not really working. I need something that's at max 1cm in size and simple. A wireless mini camera could do the trick, it would start streaming when in the vicinity of my WiFi, but the problem is the privacy laws in my country. If the cat entered someone's property with the camera, I could be sued. So I need an alternative, some simple small signal emitting device or something that can be picked up by my WiFi so that I know he's around, nothing more.

I should mention that I have no idea how these stuff actually work, so something I've said here could sound dumb I guess.

Comment: What do they use on birds?

Comment: A cat is a self-actuated transmitting device. A neighbours cat has figured out that the way to get into a house (not necessarily its owners!) is jump on the window sills and look inside till it finds a room with people in it, then miaow and thump its paws on the window.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is only to determine device in range, and you've located a suitable wireless camera to meet your size requirements, such a device could be used without privacy concerns if you painted over the lens. You could also simply place the camera in a completely solid enclosure. Your receiver would change from a no-signal status to a black/blank screen status, providing the notification you require.

Additionally, you may consider to find a software package that polls your network and advises you when a device is added, activated or vanishes from the network.

Your size restrictions may be too severe, though, as you also have to consider a battery to power the device and a battery smaller than a centimeter square is going to have extremely short capacity.